# Call web service at alerting in grafana

Tags: notifications, alert, grafana

I'm using Grafana and set an alert in a graph, How can I call an external API or web service when alert fired? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So the goal is to get information into an external service.  I am making the assumption that your particular external api / web service is not in the list of [supported notification channels](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/notifications/#supported-notification-types).

Personally in this case, I would suggest using the webhook notification channel option, as it gives a TON of information to work through / interact with:

```
{ 
   "dashboardId":1,
   "evalMatches":[ 
      { 
         "value":1,
         "metric":"Count",
         "tags":{ 

         }
      }
   ],
   "imageUrl":"https://grafana.com/assets/img/blog/mixed_styles.png",
   "message":"Notification Message",
   "orgId":1,
   "panelId":2,
   "ruleId":1,
   "ruleName":"Panel Title alert",
   "ruleUrl":"http://localhost:3000/d/hZ7BuVbWz/test-dashboard?fullscreen\u0026edit\u0026tab=alert\u0026panelId=2\u0026orgId=1",
   "state":"alerting",
   "tags":{ 
      "tag name":"tag value"
   },
   "title":"[Alerting] Panel Title alert"
}
```

This can be sent to any service that is capable of receiving webhooks and translating them into whatever you need for your external API endpoint, I might suggest the following:

- [integromat.com](https://integromat.com) (Free account gives 1000 operations / month)
- [n8n.io](https://n8n.io) (OSS and self-hosted but limited direct integration... does have HTTP, so you can use that to interact with whatever (including internal stuff)

Once in either of these tools, you build a webhook receiver and then a workflow that will translate the action into the formats needed by your external API / service.